# Modify an active record response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This seems like such a basic question, I can't get round it though. I get some data from the DB and serve it as JSON. Before I serve it as JSON I'd like to add a value to each hash in the array.

```
@locations.each do |location|
  if location[:image].present?
    location[:convient_new_url_value] = 'http://site.com/#{location.image}.jpg'
  end
end
```

However, I don't seem to be able to add a value to the hash. Am I taking the wrong approach?

** sorry - more info **

```
@locations = Location.find(:all, :order => "created_at")

@locations.each do |location|

  if location[:image].present?
    location[:convient_new_url_value] = 'http://site.com/#{location.image}.jpg'
  end
end 

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

The json is made in the HTML template:

```
<script>
    var location_data = <%= raw @locations.to_json() %>
</script>
```

Comment: It'd be easier if we could see what `location` actually is, and how it's being provided to the view.

Comment: Fixed that to make it clearer...

Comment: `locations` isn't a hash, it's an active record relation. Each object in that collection is an AR, not a generic hash; AFAIK there's nothing in to_json that would do anything other than inspect its actual attribtues and ignore ad-hoc stuff shoved into it. IIRC `[]=` resolved to `write_attribute`, if that attribute doesn't actually exist in the model itself, I don't think it'd be serialized.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help.

Do you have any suggestions regarding the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could probably just add a pseudo-attribute in the model (e.g., non-table-backed attribute), seems like that should be serialized, although I've never actually paid attention to see if it is.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to create a method in your model for `convient_new_url_value` and pass it to `to_json`:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def convient_new_url_value
    "http://site.com/#{self.image}.jpg" if self.image.present?
  end
end

<script>
  var location_data = <%= raw @locations.to_json(:methods => :convient_new_url_value) %>
</script>
```

All your controller has to do is get the locations from the DB:

```
@locations = Location.all.order(:created_at)
```